# looking for ways of avoiding python json.dumps running out of memory

Tags: python, json, memory

I am running a python script on an Ubuntu box which collects a lot of data into a tree-like JSON structure and then dumps it all at once into a file. It crashes for large trees with the following message:

```
outs.write(json.dumps(dJSON,encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False, indent=indent_val))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
   data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
MemoryError
```

I can try moving to a bigger box with more memory but it might not be available. I can also rewrite the script dumping JSON into the file in chunks, but this will require significant code changes which I am trying to avoid.

So the question is: **Is there any other way of enabling export of larger JSON trees into a file?**

Comment: It depends on the data type: if you want to dump a large list of objects you could dump individually each element or otherwise use a library that allow a stream like dumping but I can't find one now.

Comment: You are converting to a huge string, and then writing. Have you tried `json.dump(dJSON, outs, ...)`, to write directly to your file instead?